# Tuning of PPO metaparameters: a high level overview of what each parameter does

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am using the PPO algorithm implemented by tensorforce: https://github.com/reinforceio/tensorforce . It works great and I am very happy with the results.

However, I notice that there are many metaparameters available to give to the PPO algorithm:

```
 # the tensorforce agent configuration ------------------------------------------
    network_spec = [
        dict(type='dense', size=256),
        dict(type='dense', size=256),
    ]

    agent = PPOAgent(
        states=environment.states,
        actions=environment.actions,
        network=network_spec,
        # Agent
        states_preprocessing=None,
        actions_exploration=None,
        reward_preprocessing=None,
        # MemoryModel
        update_mode=dict(
            unit='episodes',
            # 10 episodes per update
            batch_size=10,
            # Every 10 episodes
            frequency=10
        ),
        memory=dict(
            type='latest',
            include_next_states=False,
            capacity=200000
        ),
        # DistributionModel
        distributions=None,
        entropy_regularization=0.01,
        # PGModel
        baseline_mode='states',
        baseline=dict(
            type='mlp',
            sizes=[32, 32]
        ),
        baseline_optimizer=dict(
            type='multi_step',
            optimizer=dict(
                type='adam',
                learning_rate=1e-3
            ),
            num_steps=5
        ),
        gae_lambda=0.97,
        # PGLRModel
        likelihood_ratio_clipping=0.2,
        # PPOAgent
        step_optimizer=dict(
            type='adam',
            learning_rate=1e-3
        ),
        subsampling_fraction=0.2,
        optimization_steps=25,
        execution=dict(
            type='single',
            session_config=None,
            distributed_spec=None
        )
    )
```

So my question is: is there a way to understand, intuitively, the meaning / effect of all these metaparameters and use this intuitive understanding to improve training performance?

So far I have reached - from a mix of reading the PPO paper and the literature around, and playing with the code - to the following conclusions. Can anybody complete / correct?

- effect of **network_spec**: this is size of the 'main network'. Quite classical: need it big enough to get valuable predictions, not too big either otherwise it is hard to train.
- effect of the parameters in **update_mode**: this is how often the network updates are performed.

  - *batch_size* is how many used for a batch update. Not sure of the effect neither what this exactly means in practice (are all samples taken from only 10 batches of the memory replay)?
  - *frequency* is how often the update is performed. I guess having frequency high would make the training slower but more stable (as sample from more different batches)?
  - *unit*: no idea what this does
- **memory**: this is the replay memory buffer.

  - *type*: not sure what this does or how it works.
  - *include_next_states*: not sure what this does or how it works
  - *capacity*: I think this is how many tuples (state, action, reward) are stored. I think this is an important metaparameter. In my experience, if this is too low compared to the number of actions in one episode, the learning is very bad. I guess this is because it must be large enough to store MANY episodes, otherwise the network learns from correlated data - which is bad.
- **DistributionMode**: guess this is the model for the distribution of the controls? No idea what the parameters there do.
- **PGModel**: No idea what the paramaters there do. Would be interesting to know if some should be tweaked / which ones.
- **PGLRModel**: idem, no idea what all these parameters do / if they should be tweaked.
- **PPOAgend**: idem, no idea what all these parameters do / if they should be tweaked.

**Summary**

So in summary, would be great to get some help about:

- Which parameters should be tweaked
- How should these parameters be tweaked? Is there a 'high level intuition' about how they should be tweaked / in which circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

Some investigation about the memory dict: The current type is `latest`, which means you're not using a memory replay, but a latest memory. Switching to replay may help.
Also, `include_next_state` means that you store tuples (state, action, reward, next state). It's not a real parameter though, because in PPO it must be set to `False`, otherwise an error is raised.
Your interpretation of `capacity` looks OK.

About the update mode spec dict, your current settings mean that : every 10 (`frequency`) episodes (`unit`), you pull a batch of 10 (`batch_size`) episodes (`unit`) from the memory (the pulling method is defined through the memory dict), and you perform an optimization step over this batch. Be aware that the `unit` defines both the unit of the optimization frequency and the type of the object fetched from the memory.